# Having Two Foreign Key Constraints Reference the Same Primary Key and both use ON UPDATE CASCADE

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cycle, ssms

I am having some trouble with mysql management studio where it is giving me the error

```
Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 65
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__Likes__LikeeId__5A846E65' on table 'Likes' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 65
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Here is the code related to Likes table, The profile table is the one where we get our foreign key from. The issue is its saying i cant have both the foreign key constraints because it creates a cycle, but I don't see why this is the case.

```
CREATE TABLE Profile (
ProfileId VARCHAR(24),
OwnerSSN VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
Age INTEGER NOT NULL,
AgeRangeStart INTEGER NOT NULL,
AgeRangeEnd INTEGER NOT NULL,
GeoRange INTEGER NOT NULL,
Gender VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
Hobbies VARCHAR(50),
Height DECIMAL(2,1) NOT NULL,
Weight INTEGER NOT NULL,
HairColor VARCHAR(20),
ProfileCreationDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
ProfileModDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
Active BIT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ProfileId),
FOREIGN KEY (OwnerSSN) REFERENCES Customer(SSN),
CHECK(Age < 120 AND Age >= 17),
CHECK(AgeRangeStart >= 17 AND AgeRangeEnd >= AgeRangeStart),
CHECK(GeoRange > 0 ) );

CREATE TABLE Likes (
LikerId VARCHAR(24),
LikeeId VARCHAR(24),
Date_Time DATETIME ,
PRIMARY KEY (LikeeId, LikerId, Date_Time) ,
FOREIGN KEY(LikerId) REFERENCES Profile(ProfileId)
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(LikeeId) REFERENCES Profile(ProfileId)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Btw `The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.` from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is when you need to start using triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_UpdateLikee BEFORE UPDATE
ON Profile FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Likes 
SET likeeId = NEW.ProfileId
Where LikeeId = Profile.ProfileId

CREATE TRIGGER tr_UpdateLiker BEFORE UPDATE
ON Profile FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Likes 
SET likerId = NEW.ProfileId
Where LikerId = Profile.ProfileId
```